# VS2015 + tsconfig.json + Message: validation against a prohibited schema succeeded

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm using visual studio community 2015 with a TypeScript Cordova project. I added an `exclude` array object to tsconfig.json and I get the following message `Validation against a prohibited schema succeeded`.  Why is the message appearing?
[image]

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

[image]

tsconfig wiki documentation https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

Comment: `The "files" property cannot be used in conjunction with the "exclude" property. If both are specified then the "files" property takes precedence.` from the link you provided. It might be related?

Comment: @gustav Thanks for the help!  The link is related.  When I remove the files array object, the message is removed from the output window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Validation against a prohibited schema succeeded. Why is the message appearing

The error message is misleading, but its because you are using `files` with `exclude`. They should not be used in conjunction and this fact is documented here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json#details

Comment: Thanks for the help! The error message is definitely misleading.  I was using the schema description and it was incorrect in describing the functionality.  Issue was added to typescript github [https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5241](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5241)
Removing the `file` object solves the problem.

On another note, I really like the idea of globbing and hope TypeScript adopts the feature.